# Dynamically create tooltip for an element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, tooltip, dynamically-generated

I am trying to show a tooltip when user selects random text on the page - think of annotating text.

I was able to dynamically create `v-tooltip` component. I have selected element in JS, but having trouble wrapping it with `v-tooltip` component. I was able to wrap it, but the tooltip is positioned to the top of the page, not on the wrapped element itself. I am also not sure my approach is the best one either.

Here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/6xk7zLv9/

Is there better way to dynamically generate Vue components and insert into the DOM? How can I correctly attach tooltip to the selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a side prop (top/bottom/left/right) on the tooltip.

The activator slot is also optional, instead you can use the `position-x` and `position-y` props to place it wherever you want without replacing DOM elements: https://codepen.io/kaelwd/pen/LYWLxVe?editors=1010

`window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()` will give you the position of the current selection: https://codepen.io/kaelwd/pen/poewRaE?editors=1010
If you want to get really fancy you can call `getClientRects` instead and have the tooltip follow the end of the selection: https://codepen.io/kaelwd/pen/vYxZgjb?editors=1010

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getClientRects